# PowerShell list users in a group linked to folders on file share

Tags: powershell, loops

I have a Specific OU with groups that we use to control access to a few specific folder on a file share, lets says fileshare1, fileshare2 and fileshar3.

```
OU=example2,OU=example1,OU=Groups,DC=domain1,DC=domain2,DC=example,DC=uk
```

I need to get a list of users that are members of the groups that are being used on fileshare1... does anyone have a method of being able to do this? whether its to get powershell to loop through the security section of each folder to get the groups being used...

For each group I need to list, the folder name and who has access.

I'm looking on google, but kinda drawing up blanks...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You are trying to get information about users with their permissions on a fileshare, so why the title _"add single user to multiple groups in specific OU"_ Apparently this question is not about adding a user to a series of groups at all.. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68904412/edit) and give it a better title

Comment: Dit you manage to achieve what you wanted, or do you need additional help?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following:

```
$ou = "OU=example2,OU=example1,OU=Groups,DC=domain1,DC=domain2,DC=example,DC=uk"
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase $ou
$fileshare = "\\server\share\"
$folders = Get-ChildItem $fileshare -Directory
foreach($folder in $folders){
    $accessRights =  Get-Acl -Path $folder
    $groupsWithAccess = @()
    foreach($group in $accessRights.Access){
        $groupName = $group.identityReference.value.split("\")[-1]
        $getGroup = $groups | Where-Object {($_.samAccountName -eq $groupName -or $_.name -eq $groupName)}
        if($getGroup){
            $groupsWithAccess += $getGroup
        }
    }
    $memberObject = @()
    foreach($groupWithAccess in $groupsWithAccess){
        $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupWithAccess.samAccountName | Where-Object {($_.objectClass -eq "user")}
    
        <# Uncomment if you wish to add one layer of nested groups
        $nestedGroups = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupWithAccess.samAccountName | Where-Object {($_.objectClass -eq "group")}
        foreach($nestedGroup in $nestedGroups){
            $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupWithAccess.samAccountName | Where-Object {($_.objectClass -eq "user")}
                $memberObject += New-Object psobject -Property @{
                fileshare = $accessRights.Path.Split("\")[-1]
                group = $groupWithAccess.name
                members = $members.name -join ";"
            }
        }
        #>

        $memberObject += New-Object psobject -Property @{
            fileshare = $accessRights.Path.Split("\")[-1]
            group = $groupWithAccess.name
            members = $members.name -join ";"
        }
    }
}
$memberObject | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Temp\test.csv" -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation
```

The above will loop through the folders, get the access rights for the folder, match the groups from the ou with access, queries the members, queries the members of nested groups (commented out), than creates an object and outputs it to a csv in C:\Temp\test.csv.

You could also use this for a single folder by removing the Get-Childitem and losing the foreach loop through the folders.

```
$ou = "OU=example2,OU=example1,OU=Groups,DC=domain1,DC=domain2,DC=example,DC=uk"
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase $ou
$fileshare = "\\server\fileshare1"
$accessRights =  Get-Acl -Path $fileshare
$groupsWithAccess = @()
foreach($group in $accessRights.Access){
    $groupName = $group.identityReference.value.split("\")[-1]
    $getGroup = $groups | Where-Object {($_.samAccountName -eq $groupName -or $_.name -eq $groupName)}
    if($getGroup){
        $groupsWithAccess += $getGroup
    }
}
$memberObject = @()
foreach($groupWithAccess in $groupsWithAccess){
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupWithAccess.samAccountName | Where-Object {($_.objectClass -eq "user")}
    
    <# Uncomment if you wish to add one layer of nested groups
    $nestedGroups = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupWithAccess.samAccountName | Where-Object {($_.objectClass -eq "group")}
    foreach($nestedGroup in $nestedGroups){
        $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupWithAccess.samAccountName | Where-Object {($_.objectClass -eq "user")}
            $memberObject += New-Object psobject -Property @{
            fileshare = $accessRights.Path.Split("\")[-1]
            group = $groupWithAccess.name
            members = $members.name -join ";"
        }
    }
    #>

    $memberObject += New-Object psobject -Property @{
        fileshare = $accessRights.Path.Split("\")[-1]
        group = $groupWithAccess.name
        members = $members.name -join ";"
    }
}
$memberObject | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Temp\test.csv" -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation
```

Please, since you have not showed any code you have tried yourself, make sure to read this code and try to fully understand what is happening. Then adjust it to your needs and finally try and test it out. Good luck!